What is the best citation generator?
I'm working on an essay for my Spanish class and I need to include citations for the first time. Since I don't know how to write them myself, I was thinking of using a citation generator. I tried using MyBib, but it couldn't find simple websites like Wikipedia. Can you recommend the best citation generator?

Define "best". Otherwise, this would be opinion-based, I believe. Also, beware MyBib and related sites, because they're all actually identical sites under different URLs.

Consider using a reference manger. The three most popular and best options are Citavi, Mendeley, and Zotero. All three allow you to to drag and drop a PDF file onto their interface and will automatically create a reference from that. Alternatively you can enter a DOI and the apps will look up the bibliographic data for you. Or you can manually enter the necessary information.
If you connect these reference managers with Word, they will automatically create and insert a reference list and well-formatted citations in your Word document. If you plan to write many papers, making yourself familiar with these three apps and choosing one for you will make your writing life so much easier. They are the standard for academic writing.
For citing non-scientific sources you'll need to learn the basics of the citation style for your style guide (e.g. APA, MLA, Chicago etc.). No citation generator can understand the different formats of web pages, for example, and automatically extract the author or publication date from them. You'll need to do that manually.
